# PDFBox: How to set fallback font for text writing

Tags: unicode, pdfbox

I am creating a PDF based on user input and user can enter english or Chinese text using following code

```
contentStream.beginText();
contentStream.setFont(font, fontSize);
contentStream.newLineAtOffset(startX, startY);
contentStream.showText(text);
contentStream.endText();
```

I am getting error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+7B11 in font OpenSans-Regular

at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDCIDFontType2.encode(PDCIDFontType2.java:363)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font.encode(PDType0Font.java:398)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDFont.encode(PDFont.java:323)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showTextInternal(PDPageContentStream.java:508)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream.showText(PDPageContentStream.java:471)
```

Font is OpenSans-Regular. This font does not contain Glyph for `笑解千`

How can I add fallback font to PDFBox so that if it does not find glyph in one font another can be used?

version: pdfbox-2.0.9

Adding font like below

```
PDFont openSansRegular = PDType0Font.load(document, MyLayout.class.getResourceAsStream(OPENSANS_REGULAR_PATH));
```

Comment: You have to split your text into pieces which each can be drawn using a given font and call `showText` for each piece separately, setting the appropriate font right before.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, at present I am checking whether font is able to encode a character or not and if not then use another font.

Comment: Exactly so you do split the text. (It may look cumbersome but PDFBox only has a low level text support; other libraries which offer replacement font handling effectively do the same under the hub.)

Comment: @VJDev how do you check if a font is able to encode a character or not?